# Drop Shadow Affect On Form Disappears Completely Even After Re-Focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have found some code online to add a drop shadow affect to my forms - works quite well and adds a touch of professionalism to my application.

Code looks like this:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Const DROPSHADOW = &H20000
        Dim cParam As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cParam.ClassStyle = cParam.ClassStyle Or DROPSHADOW
        Return cParam
    End Get
End Property
```

My problem is that when I first launch this form, the drop shadow appears.  However, if I click off this form the drop shadow disappears (as expected as it's no longer the form in focus).  But when I click back onto the form, the drop shadow affect never returns to the form.

The ONLY way I can achieve this is to use Form.TopMost = True, however, that makes the form go on top of every other window open which is not what I want.  I only want it topmost in my application.  I have even used Form.ShowDialog() and Form.ShowDialog(Me), but all have the same affect.

Is there anyway around this, as it's such a shame to add this nice looking feature for only a few seconds.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try re applying the style in the GotFocus event of the form?

Comment: How does this add "professionalism"? The operating system's themes already add whatever shadows the user wants to have on their windows. The `CS_DROPSHADOW` style is intended to be used for a very specific purpose: to emphasize that a window is temporary and floating on top of another. Like a menu or a pop-up. It's not just there to look cool. To emphasize this fact, it is worth pointing out that the effect of this flag is disabled if the user turns off the "Show shadows under menus" option in the environment preferences.

Comment: Well sorry for trying to add some 'nice touches' to my application! And for the record, I am only applying the drop shadow to pop out temporary floating forms, not every single one. If the operating system's theme was working as it should, I shouldn't need to apply a drop shadow at all.  And if the user turns off the shadows option then that is their choice.  I'm not trying to force anything upon them. I was merely pointing out the fact that when the window gets re-focused the drop shadow doesn't reappear.

Comment: You are missing the whole point. Because the drop shadow is designed for temporary pop-up windows, it goes away when the window loses the focus. Temporary pop-up windows (e.g. menus) do not lose the focus without being closed.